# What happens internally when I return a reference parameter passed to a function?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have the following function:

```
int f(int& x)
{
    x++;
    return x;
}
```

First question, does the return statement copy the value of the reference x since the function is not returning an int&.

Second question, why can't I call the function with a literal? What if I did want to call the function sometimes with a literal sometimes with a value? I tried overloading with

```
int f(int x)
{
  x++;
  return x;
}
```

It compiles if I call with literal. But when I pass a variable I get ambiguous call error. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Ambiguous -> remove the first function. But what exactly do you want your function f to do?

Comment: About the first question, can you give an example usage of function f ?

Comment: check out this link http://courses.washington.edu/css342/zander/css332/passby.html i think this is what you want

Comment: Your function modifies the original object passed to it. How did you plan to call it with a literal??? Literals are not modifiable. You need to decide first what you function should do (and what it shouldn't do). Once you decide that, we'l be able to figure out the proper implementation approach. WIthout it the question is nonsensical.

Comment: @Gerontidis I can't imagine any usage for this. First time learning this stuff and I had to ask this to get clarity.

Comment: @WaqasAhmed thanks for that link. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
int F(const int& x) { return x + 1; }
int F(int& x) { x++; return x; }
```

Comment: this compiles and works when passing a literal value. But I don't understand why? How can the first function take a literal when it's asking for a constant reference?

Comment: @bkarj: as the reference is const, the value can be passed instead of the variable.

Comment: @bkarj: or a temporary variable is created.

Comment: @bkarj passing a literal creates a temporary, and a temporarily can be bound to a const reference but not to a non-const reference.